# Configuring Auto Scaling options are greyed out - Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, autoscaling

I deployed a Java application to Windows Azure cloud using Virtual Machine by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8OyTfQPn1I. Now I want to apply autoscaling. However when I go to the "scale" tab, the options are greyed out and I am unable to turn on scaling.

P.S.- I have already created an availability set and added standard instance VMs of same configuration to it.

Please do help. 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Autoscaling in Azure Virtual Machines requires that you pre-create all the VMs in an [availability set](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2014/03/17/windows-azure-availability-sets.aspx), and then shutdown/deallocate those not currently needed. I suspect that your VMs are not in an availability set.

Comment: I have already created an availability set and have added VMs of similar configuration to the availability set.

Comment: Are you using Basic instances? Autoscaling can only be configured for Standard instances. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. No, I am using standard instances.